# Recurring event in PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, calendar, recurring-billing, recurring

Hi there I'd like to make a recurring event based on calendar basis. The thing I want to ask is this: How to trigger the event? If the client doesn't login or open the webapp to trigger the event in the constructor, how do I make the code to run anyways.

I know cron jobs maybe the solution, but is there any other solution?(I want to avoid cron jobs).

Comment: Why do you want to avoid using CRON?

Comment: question: what sort of thing do you want to do with this recurring (scheduled) event? ie updating values inside a db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that job should be triggered to keep the server in a good state, it should be run using a cron job, if its a database management, the database manager have the event's table to make cron jobs, if it's needed for only for the user, it can be a workload safe if you just don't do it until user login. You can manually login to trigger the event too, to an admin page maybe.

Comment: I want to write to db annually, monthly etc. for billing purposes. Has PhPMyadmin event table for this job?

Comment: Yes, you can use [Events](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html) to trigger MySQL Queries in X amount of time, as an example of how to do this, you can check [this tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-events/) of how to do that.

Comment: thanks a lot Ricardo! If this works for me, it will save me a lot of time, reading and coding cronjobs...thumbs up

Answer (score 3):

You have to have something running in order for this to work; a cron is ideal for this, as it can run a script at regular intervals to check for things like events.

Without that, you are left by this being triggered by user action, but like you said, that user might not always log in to trigger it.

You could modify your code to have any user trigger actions for all users. It's a little more complex, as you'd need to allow for multiple users logging in at the same time when you only want one of them to trigger stuff. I would set up a table in your database to keep track of the last time things were triggered, and then if the gap since then and now is large enough when a user logs in, add a new entry in the table with the time now to prevent another user triggering this, and trigger the bits you need to run.

Like I said though, this won't be a perfect solution, and I really would recommend using cron. Is there any reason why you want to avoid using cron?

Comment: Thanks Ashley for your response. The only thing prevents me from using cron is that I'm not very familiar with it. But if this is the best way to do it, I'll give it a try. Thanks again.

Comment: A cron is very easy to set up, the Wikipedia page on it is worth having a look at, it explains the syntax used to determine how often a task runs. Typically, a cron job is added via "crontab -e" over the command line, using whichever CLI editor is set up as the default (most often Vi/Vim). I think a lot of typical Linux distros these days actually provide a commented out example to help you along too.